# Non linear regression in R Exponential curve fitting

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear

I am trying to fit an exponential model to some data. The data is:

```
Wavelength  aCDOM
350.01  0.80605
350.22  0.78302
350.43  0.78302
350.64  0.78302
350.85  0.78302
351.06  0.78302
351.27  0.78302
351.48  0.78302
351.68  0.75999
351.89  0.75999
352.1   0.75999
352.31  0.75999
352.52  0.75999
352.73  0.73696
352.94  0.73696
353.15  0.73696
353.36  0.73696
353.57  0.73696
353.78  0.73696
353.99  0.73696
354.2   0.73696
354.41  0.73696
354.62  0.73696
354.83  0.73696
355.04  0.73696
355.25  0.71393
355.46  0.71393
355.67  0.71393
```

I know that the best model fit this type of data is an exponential function in the for `y ~ a * exp(-b * c)` where `a` is the absorbance estimate at the reference wavelength, `b` is the spectral slope which is the value I am looking for, and `c` is the wavelength minus the reference wavelength (440nm). I have tried using the `nls` function by estimating the starting parameters following the method outlined in Fox (2002) but I keep getting the following error in `nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts)`:

```
singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
```

The formula I am using is `model1 <- nls(St0104 ~ a * exp(-b * (Wavelength-440)), start = list(a=0.1, b=0.0012), trace=T)`, I'm not even if I have calculated the starting parameters correctly.

I have tried instead to plot the log of `Y` and do linear as well as polynomial regression, but I know this is not correct for this data and the residuals are horrible. I'm pretty new to R but I have tried everything I can but this is driving me nuts can anybody help please?

Comment: 1. The two variables you gave in your data (Wavelength, aCDOM) do not match the two variables in your model (St0104, Wavelength). $\,$ 2. the $Y$ variable in the data that you have supplied is discrete. Indeed, it appears to be integers between 31 and 35, all scaled by a constant. What is it?

Comment: hi sorry I should have mentioned the name of the y variable is St0104 the values are actually the absorbance of CDOM at 440nm over the wavelength range of a sample called St0104.I only gave a small set of the full data as it was quite long. X values are wavelength Y are the a440 (absorbance at 440nm).

Comment: How is absorbance measured? Why are the values all multiples of a constant?

Comment: (1) The residuals will be awful because the $(x,y)$ data trace out a step function (having only five levels). (2) The narrow range of y-values (varying less than $\pm 6\%$ from their middle) indicates there is little difference between fitting $(x,y)$ or fitting $(x,\log(y))$. (3) One would guess the $y$ values are either counts or rounded decimals that have been converted (via some kind of calibration information) to absorbance values. A maximum likelihood estimate suitable for *the raw data* ought to converge and do a good job of estimating $b$.

Comment: The Y values were calculated by choosing a wavelength of interest (in this case 440nm) and using the formula a440 = 2.303(A440) where 2.303 is a constant and A440 is the (corrected) absorbance at that wavelength. I used a spec fluorometer to measure absorbance of the sample. I am trying to calculate the spectral slope (SCDOM) which is estimated from the slope of an exponential curve of a440 as a function of wavelength. Again I am new to R and stats so I find R a bit confusing. I tried this regression in Matlab and it works fine if I use  exp function with 2 terms but I cant figure it out in R.

Comment: **This is an irreproducible result:** when I run your code with your data and starting values, `nls` completes successfully with a reasonable set of estimates.

Answer (score 0):

For the formula, include an I() to indicate that the asterisks are to be used as arithmetic multipliers rather than crossing variables as is the standard for formula writing in R, i.e. I(a * exp(-b * (Wavelength-440))). See http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html.

Comment: An identical example in the manual page for `nls` does not require the use of `I`, nor do any of the other examples there.  The code as given in the question works.

Comment: `nls`  doesn't use quite the same interface for formulas that `lm` uses, so this shouldn't be an issue.